# How to increase the width of individual collection-item

Tags: css, materialize

I am new to Materialize CSS and I am stuck with the width of collection-item. I want the width of the collection item to occupy the entire space, I have inside a container.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="left-align">
       <ul class="collection">
           <li class="collection-item">
               <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="a" id="checkbox">
               <label for="checkbox">
                   {{ yyy }}
               </label><br>
               <label for="checkbox">
                   {{ xxx }}</label>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your container has a class called "container", materialize automatically makes your container div 70% of the window width.